# How to check the array key was set or not by user in PHP~?

Tags: php, arrays

E.g:

I create an array in PHP by :

```
$arr1 = array('123','3434','43434');
```

or

```
$arr2 = array('45'=>'24','56'=>'34');
```

So,I want to check that the $arr1's key didn't set by user and the $arr2's key had been set by user!?

In another words , could I do that in this way:

```
if('key was set by PHP'){ // 
  // do something
}
else{
 // key was set by user.do something...
}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: About the only way you could do this is to only use string indices when you manually define the key - that way, you can differentiate between the PHP-generated integer indices. Could you explain a bit as to why you want/need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't keep track of what action set up an item in an array.

So, you cannot find out if a key has been determined automatically *(as the biggest integer key + 1)* or defined by the developer who wrote the PHP script.

If the keys set up by the developer where strings *(and not integers -- note that `'45'` counts as an integer, when used as an array key)*, you could do something : the keys generated by PHP would be the only integers ones.

But, as this is not your case *(all keys are integers, be it written by the developer or created automatically)*, there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having control on

```
$arr2 = array('45'=>'24','56'=>'34');
```

So,wt you can do is append some char in key to identify it has been added by user :

```
eg: $arr2 = array('u45'=>'24','u56'=>'34');
```